# Why my SWT application does not work?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I am trying to create a Hello World SWT application using Eclipse. I follow all instructions and in the end my program does not work.

This is my code:

```
import gnu.gcj.xlib.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;


public class HelloWorldSWT {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("Hello world!");
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

}
```

And this is my error messages:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The constructor Shell(Display) is undefined
    The method readAndDispatch() is undefined for the type Display
    The method sleep() is undefined for the type Display
    The method dispose() is undefined for the type Display

   at HelloWorldSWT.main(HelloWorldSWT.java:13)
```

Does anybody know how I can check what is wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're importing a wrong Display class. The right one should be

```
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display
```

Comment: When I replace "import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;" by "org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display", the Eclipse writes me that I have some conflicts. The I have removed the first line of my code (import gnu.gcj.xlib.Display;).  Then when I try to run my program I still have some error messages:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Shell cannot be resolved to a type
 Shell cannot be resolved to a type

   at HelloWorldSWT.main(HelloWorldSWT.java:12)

Comment: You must let the import to `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell` and add the import `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display`.

Answer (score 0):

Clean all in your folder, do it again, import swt create proj, check build path add class, run
this should work.
If not , right click , click clean up, click source... organize imports, run again. Should work, if error no

> swt.dll

in your library, copy all

> swt.dll

to your  library path. Should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I made the same mistake. My issue was on the second step: I selected to import "org.eclipse.swt". Instead, you must select the correct one for your operating system. In my case, this was "org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86". Once you've done this, the rest of the steps in the tutorial should work as expected.

The answers above, while correct, may assume a bit more knowledge than most completing this tutorial will have.